# Convert .tmp image received via cURL to .jpeg

Tags: php, image, curl

I need some help.
So i've created a php script that sending data with image via cURL.
Here's the scenario:

I've uploaded a image,then I will pass the image that has a .jpeg file extension name via cURL.

On my receiver,I'm receiving the image but image file extension name to .tmp
Do I have a way to convert it to .jpeg again before uploading it?

Here's my code on passing the image:

```
    $data = array(
    "filename"=>$first_param,
    "transno"=>$transno,
    "type"=>$type,
    "refno"=>$refno,
    "custno"=>$custno,
    "imei"=>$imei
);
$dataFields = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
$fields = array('uploaded_file' => '@' . $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],     'filename'=>$_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');


$url = "http://url/directory/phpname.php?".$dataFields;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Now here's my code for receiving it:

```
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$transno = $_GET['transno'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$refno = $_GET['refno'];
$custno = $_GET['custno'];
$remarks="";
$imei = $_GET['imei'];


$upload = new Upload();

$upload->Upload($filename, $transno, $type, $refno, $custno, $remarks,     $imei, $_FILES);
```

The received image will be $_FILES.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're uploading it directly from the temp directory. You should use `move_uploaded_file()` on it first, so it has the correct name, then upload it.